# Xamarin forms : bug in master detail Page

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a bug in my Xamarin Forms app. When I was coding page to appear content "master-detail" when the user chose on the last page. The content doesn't appear.

During debugging, the app work without any code errors; however, it appears without any content. I am using the Firebase database.

Firebase helper:

```
public async Task<List<Cuts>> GetAction()
{
    return (await firebase
          .Child("Action")
          .OnceAsync<Cuts>()).Select(item => new Cuts
          {
              name = item.Object.name,
              link = item.Object.link,
              poster = item.Object.poster
          }).ToList();
}
```

The page which the users choose from:

```
public partial class ActionFilms : ContentPage
{
    FirebaseHelper firebaseHelper = new FirebaseHelper();
    public ActionFilms()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected async override void OnAppearing()
    {

        base.OnAppearing();
        var allPersons = await firebaseHelper.GetAction();
        act.ItemsSource = allPersons;
    }

   public void act_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var acctionn = e.PreviousSelection as Cuts;
        App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new ActionMaster(acctionn));
    }
}
```

The code of master-detail Page "which the content does not appear at here":

```
public partial class ActionMaster : ContentPage
{
    public ActionMaster(Cuts acctionn)
    {
        
        BindingContext = acctionn;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: have you stepped through your code in the debugger?

Comment: Please add more information about what happens during debugging.

Comment: when debugging it its work and don't there any errors.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Do you mean that `ActionMaster` page not shows content when release mode? You could add `Console.Writeline(acctionn)` inside `ActionMaster` to check whehter data is null first.